# What is the Octorok ring good for?

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-seasons

Vasu told me that this ring can turn me into an Octorok.  While that is kinda neat from an aesthetic standpoint, does this serve any purpose in the game other than looks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is almost no practical purpose for the Octo Ring**. It's supposed to be just a fun ring which serves no useful purpose. However, the ring does grant immunity to being captured by Like-Likes while it is in use ([source](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Octo_Ring)). Save the space in your ring box for more useful rings.